# Minimal plan for our 70 users to have a SharePoint site and multiple yammer groups (public and private)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, licensing, yammer

We are a company with 70 users, and as the first stage we need to have have the following:

1. Single SharePoint site, we can use the root site to have 10 document libraries.
2. we need to set 10 yammer groups and embed them inside SharePoint.

So can anyone advice what is the minimal plan we need to achieve the above? Is Office 365 E1 sufficient for our case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, Office 365 E1 is minimal enterprise plan sufficient for your use case.

Office 365 E1 Plan supports using of SharePoint online as well as Yammer.

Check below documentations for more information:

1. [Microsoft 365 and Office 365 plan options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-365-platform-service-description/office-365-plan-options)
2. [Compare Office 365 enterprise plans (E1/E3/E5)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-365/enterprise/compare-office-365-plans)